# Error Code 13 in Mysql on UNIX. Can anyone Help me?

Tags: sql, unix, mysql, database-administration

I'm Using MySQL Server on UNIX System,

when i'm execute the below query

```
SELECT * INTO '/home/krunal/backupData/myBackup1.txt' FROM tbl_Property;
```

it shows the error

> ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't Create /Write to file >'/home/krunal/backupData/myBackup1.txt' (Errorcode : 13)

Can anyone tell me that how can i solve this error

`**Note**` : I have all the permission on dir backupData , Read , Write , Execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You messed up with /home/krunal/backupData/ permissions. To fix:

```
  chown root:root /home/krunal/backupData/
  chmod 1777 /home/krunal/backupData/
  /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Source: [permissions](http://nixcraft.com/showthread.php/14260-ERROR-1-(HY000)-Can-t-create-write-to-file-tmp-sql_9f3_0-MYI-(Errcode-13))