# Creating a cron to execute a daily mysql dump

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I want to create a cron job to execute the following mysql dump on a daily basis and save a csv file to a designated directory. However, I am trying to execute the command from my command line and it throws an error. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
mysql -u dom_hemma -ppasswordhere -D dom_hemma -e "SELECT * FROM `wp7f_posts` WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'flamingo_inbound' INTO OUTFILE '/home/domhemma/public_html/access/access.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY `,` LINES TERMINATED BY `\n`;"
```

I expect a csv file to be produced
Instead I get the "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error related to the quotation

Comment: This is what I am also thinking, I just can't figure out where

Comment: try this  :    SELECT * FROM wp7f_posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'flamingo_inbound' INTO OUTFILE '/home/domhemma/public_html/access/access.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: Thanks! That solved the syntax error issue but now I have a permissions issue (errcode: 13). It can't write to the file designated.

Comment: maybe take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936577/error-code-13-in-mysql-on-unix-can-anyone-help-me